# Ruby printing using here documents

Tags: ruby, heredoc

I am completely new to Ruby. I am trying to print the type and the name of a class using a method but I am getting this syntax error I cannot figure out:

```
Code/oop.rb:47: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input
    puts <<TYPE, <<EOF, <<NAME
               ^
```

Here is my code:

```
def whatClass()
    class_type = self.type
    class_name = self.name

    puts <<TYPE, <<EOF, <<NAME
        class_type
    TYPE
        \n
    EOF
        class_name
    NAME     
end
```

Comment: What is <<TYPE,  <<EOF, <<NAME ?

Comment: String names. I have read that this a way to build and print strings.

Comment: can you add your visual expectations ?

Comment: type + endl + name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple errors.

Preamble: `type` and `name`are no standard methods. In the following example I replace it with strings.

When you use Here-Documents like this:

```
puts <<HEREDOC
  Heredoc
HEREDOC
```

Then the closing `HEREDOC` must start in column 0 and may have no trailing spaces. When you have leading spaces, then you must start with `<<-HEREDOC`:

```
puts <<-HEREDOC
  Heredoc
  HEREDOC
```

So your example is:

```
  def whatClass()
    class_type = 'type' #self.type undefined method `type'
    class_name = 'name' #self.name

    puts <<-TYPE, <<-EOF, <<-NAME
        class_type
    TYPE
        \n
    EOF
        class_name
    NAME
  end
```

And again: There may be no trailing spaces in `TYPE`, `EOF` and `NAME` (when I take your example with cut+paste there are trailing spaces at `NAME`).

The next error:

The output is

```
        class_type


        class_name
```

But I think you want the content of the two variables. So I think you need:

```
  def whatClass()
    class_type = 'type' #self.type undefined method `type'
    class_name = 'name' #self.name

    puts <<-TYPE, <<-EOF, <<-NAME
    #{class_type}
    TYPE
        \n
    EOF
    #{class_name}
    NAME
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
def whatClass()
    class_type = self.type
    class_name = self.name
    puts "#{class_type} \n #{class_name}"

end
```